# How to initialise a variable amount of class instances using array entries as the initialization values for each instance

Tags: c#, initialization, arguments, declaration

I want to create a variable amount of instances of ChromeDriver and give for each of them their own options (from an option array which i created earlier)

currently my code looks like this:

```
ChromeDriver[] driver = new ChromeDriver[4] 
{
    new ChromeDriver(options[0]),
    new ChromeDriver(options[1]),
    new ChromeDriver(options[2]),
    new ChromeDriver(options[3])
};
```

but the problem is the "4" should be variable.

my approach was to use a foreach and a while loop inside the {} to initialise the single ChromeDriver but c# doesnt allow that.

I am not completly sure if there is even a way to solve this problem without a huge workaround

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `driver` should be the same length as the number of `options` you have:

```
ChromeDriver[] driver = new ChromeDriver[options.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
    driver[i] = new ChromeDriver(options[i]);
```

Comment: this does not work because you already initialsed driver[] on the first line.

Comment: Apologies, I mistakenly added `()` to the end of `new ChromeDriver[options.Length];`. Try the revision and it will work

Comment: thanks a lot ive spend the half day with this. could you maybe tell me where i can find those basic rules of declaration and initialisation.

I mean even if the code work i still do not understand why the instances are not created when the array is created

Comment: @Rjinxil No problem. This is particularly relevant in this case: _The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and reference elements are set to null._ So a new 'object' array will have it's elements set to NULL by default. The article is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple LINQ statement to create the array.

```
var driver = options.Select(x => new ChromeDriver(x)).ToArray();
```